# Cannot catch Flutter web URL query parameter

Tags: flutter, url, redirect

I have 3 screens in my Flutter web app. `Home`, `Screen1` and `Screen2`. `Home` has a button which on click takes to `Screen1`. That works fine. But I want to add an additional query parameter in the URL i.e. the home screen URL in my PC is `http://localhost:53248/#/`. When the button is clicked, then URL remains the same, but it takes to `Screen1`. Now if I want to change the URL to `http://localhost:53248/#/?path=subscriptions`, I want it to navigate to `Screen2`. So in `Screen1`, I have a method namely `_getPathFromUrl()` inside `initState` that finds the URL query parameter and based on its value is supposed to  navigate to `Screen2`. **But this does not happen actually**.

**Home:**

```
void main() {
  runApp(const Home());
}

class Home extends StatelessWidget {
  const Home({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: const MyHomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyHomePage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  
  @override
  State<MyHomePage> createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Home'),
      ),
      body: Center(
        
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            const Text(
              'Her is Home',
            ),
            ElevatedButton(onPressed: (){

              Navigator.push(
                  context,
                  MaterialPageRoute(builder: (_) => const Screen1()),
                      );

            }, child: Text('Button1'))

          ],
        ),
      ),
       // This trailing comma makes auto-formatting nicer for build methods.
    );
  }
}
```

**Screen1:**

```
class Screen1 extends StatelessWidget {
  const Screen1({Key? key}) : super(key: key);


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Screen1',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: const MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyHomePage({Key? key, required this.title}) : super(key: key);


  final String title;

  @override
  State<MyHomePage> createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {

  void _getPathFromUrl(){

    print("Inside _getPathFromUrl in Landing Screen Component");

    String path_param = Uri.base.queryParameters["path"].toString(); //get parameter with attribute "para1"
    // String para2 = Uri.base.queryParameters["para2"]; //get parameter with attribute "para2"
    print(" path_param founddddd = "+path_param.toString());
    if(kIsWeb) {
      var queryParams = Uri
          .parse(window.location.href)
          .queryParameters;
      String path_param = queryParams['path'].toString();

      print(" path_param found = " + path_param.toString());

      if(path_param.trim()=="subscriptions".trim()) {
        Navigator.push(
          context,
          new MaterialPageRoute(
            builder: (context) => Screen2(),

          ),

        );
      }
    }
  }
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _getPathFromUrl();

  }
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Screen1'),
      ),
      body: Center(

        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            const Text(
              'Here is Screen1',
            ),

          ],
        ),
      ),

    );
  }
}
```

**Screen2:**

```
class Screen2 extends StatelessWidget {
  const Screen2({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Screen2',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: const MyHomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyHomePage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<MyHomePage> createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Screen2'),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(

          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            const Text(
              'Here is Screen22222',
            ),
         ],
        ),
      ),

    );
  }
}
```

The reason is  When I change the URL **manually** to be `http://localhost:53248/#/?path=subscriptions`, the browser redirects to `http://localhost:53248/#/` and in my Android Studio IDE console, I get the error:

Could not navigate to initial route.
The requested route name was: "/?path=subscriptions"
There was no corresponding route in the app, and therefore the initial route specified will be ignored and "/" will be used instead.

How can I catch the URL query parameter and based on its value, make the navigation from `Screen1` to `Screen2` ?

Comment: I would love to test this but am just too lazy with setting up a localhost for this :). One thing I wonder is why do you have two widgets returning ```MaterialApp```? I'm very used to having a single one in every project I work :).

Comment: @bqubique, no need to setup any localhost. Just run the app from IDE as web, and localhost will automatically be created. I tried with Android Studio.

Comment: @bqubique, alternatively you can run `flutter run -d chrome` command in Android Studio terminal to run the app in web platform.

Comment: I have been trying to implement the said features with go_router but to no avail, and very weirdly I don't see the point of failure either :).

Comment: By the time you call runApp it's game over. If you didn't grab the query parameters before calling runApp it's too late. Add `queryParams = Uri.parse(html.window.location.href).queryParameters;` before runApp and store that somewhere that you can refer to later. Then throughout the app you can refer back to that and find what the initial query parameters were and decide what to do based on that.

Answer (score 0):

This is my go using `go_router` from Flutter team.

**pubspec.yaml**

```
dependencies
   go_router: ^6.2.0
```

**screens.dart**

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:go_router/go_router.dart';

void main() => runApp(const MyApp());

final GoRouter _router = GoRouter(
  routes: <RouteBase>[
    GoRoute(
      path: '/',
      builder: (BuildContext context, GoRouterState state) {
        return const HomeScreen();
      },
    ),
    GoRoute(
      path: '/subs',
      builder: (BuildContext context, GoRouterState state) {
        return const DetailsScreen();
      },
    )
  ],
);

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp.router(
      routerConfig: _router,
    );
  }
}

class HomeScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  const HomeScreen({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(title: const Text('Home Screen')),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            ElevatedButton(
              onPressed: () => context.go('/subs'),
              child: const Text('Go to the Details screen'),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class DetailsScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  const DetailsScreen({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(title: const Text('Details Screen')),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <ElevatedButton>[
            ElevatedButton(
              onPressed: () => context.go('/'),
              child: const Text('Go back'),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Given these information, could you implement it in your use case? Do you need help in there too?